# Is there a way to highlight both rows of an active prop in a UIList?

Tags: python, add-on

I have 3 props in the UIlist below with the second prop being active. Each prop has two rows but only the first row is highlighted when active. Is there a way to highlight both rows of an active prop?

[image: Text]

Comment: Sorry you never got a response. I'm not sure it's possible - I'd try reporting it as a bug, just to see if they think it's doable. But I'm curious, how are you adding the sub-rows? Using `layout.row()` in UIList seems to only put it on the same row for me.

Comment: @S.Magnusson and for other future searchers. Using layout.column() you can then use that column to add multiple rows. Sorry OP, I don't know the solution to the original problem.